# Update PayPal transactions INVNUM field

Tags: paypal, nvp

Is it possible to update the transactions INVNUM (Your own invoice or tracking number) field at a later state using the NVP-API? 
I want to "update" my PayPal transactions with the final invoice numbers, so I can use the PayPal backend to get a list of all PayPal transactions and invoice numbers.
I found only solutions to receive this field, but no update hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=INVNUM and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/nvpsoap-sdks/ for examples.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I'm using the NVP-API for a while, but this well known links doesn't help (me) with this specific question.

Comment: Does anyone knows this question's answer? Please update this. I also need this information.